# 'azureml.logging' module not found

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I can't seem to get the logger to work in the online azure notesbooks workspace. I'm using python 3.6 environment.
Running this import:

```
from azureml.logging import get_azureml_logger
```

gives me the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml.logging
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is

pip install "https://azuremldownloads.blob.core.windows.net/wheels/latest/azureml.logging-1.0.79-py3-none-any.whl?sv=2016-05-31&si=ro-2017&sr=c&sig=xnUdTm0B%2F%2FfknhTaRInBXyu2QTTt8wA3OsXwGVgU%2BJk%3D"

I found the blob url here. It's inside docker container dependencies.

https://github.com/Azure/LearnAI-Bootcamp/blob/master/lab03.3_manage_conda_envs_in_aml/0_README.md

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's [installed with Azure ML Workbench](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/how-to-use-run-history-model-metrics#azure-ml-logging-api-overview).

There is (currently) no way to install this as a stand-alone package from what I can find. If you look at the `azureml` package on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-MachineLearning-ClientLibrary-Python) there is no "logging" in it.

Comment: I went looking for this and could only find it being installed in what I think was the docker container that runs the experiment.  It's from a wheel called "azureml.logging" that is a dependency of "azureml-requirements" and is installed from some Azure blob bucket.  Just FYI because this was puzzling me too, as I didn't find it in my local install of the ML workbench and my IDE was complaining about its absence.

Comment: any updates on this? I am also facing the same problem.