# Log metrics in PythonScriptStep

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

In my Azure ML pipeline I've got a PythonScriptStep that is crunching some data. I need to access the Azure ML Logger to track metrics in the step, so I'm trying to import get_azureml_logger but that's bombing out. I'm not sure what dependency I need to install via pip.

`from azureml.logging import get_azureml_logger`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml.logging'`

I came across a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438358/azureml-logging-module-not-found) but it deals with Azure Notebooks. Anyway, I tried adding that blob to my pip dependency, but it's failing with an Auth error.

```
Collecting azureml.logging==1.0.79 [91m  ERROR: HTTP error 403 while getting
https://azuremldownloads.blob.core.windows.net/wheels/latest/azureml.logging-1.0.79-py3-none-any.whl?sv=2016-05-31&si=ro-2017&sr=c&sig=xnUdTm0B%2F%2FfknhTaRInBXyu2QTTt8wA3OsXwGVgU%2BJk%3D
[0m91m  ERROR: Could not install requirement azureml.logging==1.0.79 from
https://azuremldownloads.blob.core.windows.net/wheels/latest/azureml.logging-1.0.79-py3-none-any.whl?sv=2016-05-31&si=ro-2017&sr=c&sig=xnUdTm0B%2F%2FfknhTaRInBXyu2QTTt8wA3OsXwGVgU%2BJk%3D
(from -r /azureml-environment-setup/condaenv.g4q7suee.requirements.txt
(line 3)) because of error 403 Client Error:
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. for url:
https://azuremldownloads.blob.core.windows.net/wheels/latest/azureml.logging-1.0.79-py3-none-any.whl?sv=2016-05-31&si=ro-2017&sr=c&sig=xnUdTm0B%2F%2FfknhTaRInBXyu2QTTt8wA3OsXwGVgU%2BJk%3D
```

I'm not sure how to move on this, all I need to do is to log metrics in the step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [ScriptRunConfig Section of the Monitor Azure ML experiment runs and metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-track-experiments#option-2-use-scriptrunconfig). `ScriptRunConfig` works effectively the same as a `PythonScriptStep`.

The idiom is generally to have the following in your the script of your `PythonScriptStep`:

```
from azureml.core.run import Run
run = Run.get_context()
run.log('foo_score', "bar")
```

Side note: You don't need to change your environment dependencies to use this because `PythonScriptStep`s have `azureml-defaults` installed automatically as a dependency.

Comment: Hi Anders, looks like i broke something when playing with the pip packages. Im now getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml.core'". I'm installing the following packages: ["azureml-dataprep[pandas,fuse]","tensorflow", "keras", "matplotlib"]. i know this was working before, is there a way to purge the docker image?

Comment: That’s weird! Try adding ‘azureml-defaults’ at the beginning of the list.